# Magento - Change the Scope of an Attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, scope

**How can I change the scope of anattribute from 'Global' to 'Website'.**

Is there an extension to change it or do I have to change it manually?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the scope of an attribute by going to

*catalog -> attributes -> manage attributes*

Find your attribute and click it to edit the attribute properties. Change the scope dropdown to Website and save the attribute.

[image]